# How can I mount a removable device as un-ejectable

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount, sd-card, eject

I have a Micro-SD card which I keep permanently inserted in my MacBook Pro using a nifty Mini-drive. I doubt it should matter, but this is a [13" early 2011 MacBookPro](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html), running High Sierra (hardware doesn't support upgrading to Mojave, and app store actively prevents it).

Since I use this as my long-term "tepid" storage (not disconnected "cold" storage, but not using space on my more actively used SSDs), I would prefer that it be mounted in a manner where it cannot be ejected from the OS, either through Finder, or [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) or any other means.

Is there a way of flagging the device, through Disk Utility, `fstab` or some other manner, to do so? Essentially, for it to behave like a permanent/fixed disk, as opposed to it being removable?

Comment: Go to http://dosdude1.com/mojave/ for a way to run Mojave if you're interested

Comment: It will patch the OS to run on your hardware, just check that your hardware is compatible with the patch

Comment: Good question! +1 I'd like to know if there is a flag or such that could be set, as I too find the need at times to keep a drive from being ejected. What I typically do is open a Terminal window that has been `cd`ed_ to the _root_ of the external disk, which then typically will not be ejected until that Terminal window is closed. Not an ideal solution but at least a workaround.

Comment: maybe not quite what you wanted but worth reading about Mountain.app http://blog.appgineers.de/post/101608761084/new-advanced-feature-for-nifty-minidrive-users  and here https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/43428/mountain